# Multi text views in constraint layout

Tags: android

I have 2 text views in constraint layout one is startToStartOf parent. Second text is aligned startToEndOf first text. I want just 1st line of second text align startToEndOf first text and than second line of second text align to parent .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to have the text of 2 different styles, where the first like or part of the first line is different from the rest of the text.

In such case you should use a single `TextView` and a `SpannableString` assigning different spans for different parts of the text.